# how to pass argparse arguments to another python program in unchanged condition?

Tags: python

I am working on a script under which some sub program will run.
for example **test.py** is the main program and under that **test1.py**, **test2.py**, **test3.pl** will run and I need to pass the arguments from the main program(test.py) to test1.py and test2.py program also.the arguments should be in unchanged condition. while passing to another program.

code: **test.py**

```
import argparse
import subprocess
import os

commandLineArgumentParser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-fname", "--fname",help="first name")
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-lname","--lname", help="last name")
commandLineArgumentParser.add_argument("-age","--age", help="age")
commandLineArguments = commandLineArgumentParser.parse_args()

fname = commandLineArguments.fname
lname = commandLineArguments.lname
age = commandLineArguments.age

print "%s%s%s" %(fname,lname,age)
```

I am running the program by the bellow commands :

```
python test.py -fname=abc -age=22 -lname='test a'
or 
python test.py -fname="abc test" lname='val' -age=30
or
python test.py -age=45 -lname='abc aa' fname="abc"
or 
python test.py -age=45 -lname="test"
```

now I want to grab the argument part in unchanged condition and put in one variable then we can easily pass the arguments to program easily.

For the first command the variable will hold

```
-fname=abc -age=22 -lname='test a'
```

for 2nd command

```
-fname="abc test" lname='val' -age=30
```

I was trying to grab the arguments using the bellow code but the quotas are missing by the script.

```
my_argu=''
if len(sys.argv) >1:
    for x in sys.argv:
            if x == sys.argv[0]:
                    continue
            if x == sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]:
                    my_argu =my_argu+x
            else:
                    my_argu = my_argu+x+' '
print "%s" %(my_argu)
```

for the

```
python test.py -fname="abc test" lname='val' -age=30
```

the output is :

```
abc testval30

-fname=abc test lname=val -age=30
```

as you can see quotas are missing. So I need help to solve it

Comment: Is it a mistake that you have lname with and without leading hyphen?

Comment: It was my mistake ....extreamly sorry for that...I have corrected that mistake

Comment: How do you execute the other program?

Comment: *"I am thinking to pass the arguments to another python program"* - why? Can't you `import` the appropriate function and call it directly?

Comment: I have the same question. Why do you want to do this? All this script do is parsing the arguments and pass them to another script? Why just do the parsing in the other script?

Comment: I don't know any function which will give the unchanged arguments. If you such function that will be a great help..  @jonrsharpe

Comment: actually I am trying to make one software for that purpose I need that thing.- @skyline75489

Comment: I will execute the program using `python test.py -fname=abc -age=22 -lname='test a'' ` command line

Comment: We need the full picture. This seems likely to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: There is no way to get *unchanged arguments*. Arguments are parsed by fill `sys.argv` global variable. You can try just to mimic it but you will never reproduce the original one (escapes characters). To mimic it in almost every cases you can just get the arguments that contains spaces ad quote they.

Comment: I tried `my_argu=''
if len(sys.argv) >1:
        for x in sys.argv:
                if x == sys.argv[0]:
                        continue
                if x == sys.argv[len(sys.argv)-1]:
                        my_argu =my_argu+x
                else:
                        my_argu = my_argu+x+' '` to do some mimic in the arguments but i am not getting the quotas by the above code. I need to add quota in the where ever needed in the progream

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're trying to achieve, why you need this functionality, how you're trying to implement it or what's happening instead of whatever you expect. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and **add more information**. A [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would probably be useful, for example. If the module that you're trying to interface with is *at all sanely-structured*, you probably don't need to do this at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thanks for your valuable comments. I will try my best to give more clear problem. I edited my question little bit. so that  you can understand my question more clearly. I also added my code which I was trying.

Comment: You still haven't explained **why you're doing this**. What's the program you're interfacing with, and why can't you do it directly rather than via command line arguments? If it's just a matter of quoting strings, note that `repr('foo')` gives you something useful.

Comment: *Why can't you do it directly, rather than via command line arguments?* Why not just `import test1` then call the functions with the *parsed* arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should pull these all together in one wrapper and call that instead.

```
# wrapper.py

import test, test1, test2, test3
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-fname", "--fname",help="first name")
parser.add_argument("-lname","--lname", help="last name")
parser.add_argument("-age","--age", help="age")
cli_args = parser.parse_args()

test.run(cli_args)
test1.run(cli_args)
test2.run(cli_args)
test3.run(cli_args)
```

Then in each of your `testN.py`s...

```
# test.py

def run(cli_args):
    print("Your name is {} {}".format(cli_args.fname, cli_args.lname))
    # or whatever your program does....
```

Then do:

```
$ python wrapper.py --fname Adam --lname Smith
```